# Can I inherit an erb template?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, sinatra, erb

Is there any way to have a template inherit another template? I'm not using Rails.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you inherit from another template? How would you expect to override the template, or part of it?

Comment: Like other templates do. For example parts could be generic to all of them, like footer & header.

Comment: please explain in detail what you want accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't inherit an erb template - it isn't a class. It is just a file.

EDIT:

According to @Dan's comment, I took a look on Django template inheritance and it looks very similar to Rails `content_for`. However I don't know how to use it outside of Rails. Take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield) at points 3.2 and 3.3, and [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html).

Comment: I don't think you answered the question at all. If you've had any experience with Django templates, you'd understand what he's trying to ask.

Answer (score 6):

I also really like the django template inheritance, but it's not available at least with sinatra.

The [sinatra book](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#templates) explains how you can use a `layout.erb` to define a standard page layout:

You just need to define a `views/layout.erb`file with something like:

```
<html>
  <head>..</head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then call your erb template with `erb :index` for example. Sinatra will render both templates and include the contents of your index template inside the result of the layout.erb rendering.

Comment: Is there a way to override more than one part of the template? Say, to specify the contents of the `<title>` element?

Comment: The best way to do this is probably use https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib/blob/master/lib/sinatra/content_for.rb
Then you can just use `content_for :some_key` and then use `yield_content :somekey` in your layout

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is [partials](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html) and [layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).  You can define a layout as a container for your page which has global design stuff (your CSS and javascript includes, headers and footers, etc.  Inside this view, you can `yield` to another template, and that template can render `partials`.

Comment: That's true in rails, but is it true in erb when not in rails?

Comment: No.  Rails handles those methods for you.  You can however look at the rails source code for ActionController, as it contains the appropriate methods, and you can either include the required module(s), or implement them yourself.

Comment: Yeah, i know of them, but unfortunately I'm not using Rails. I'm a  Sinatra person :)

Answer (score 0):

Now there are the framework [Rango](https://github.com/botanicus/rango), the first Ruby framework with template inheritance, and a framework-agnostic [template inheritance](https://github.com/botanicus/template-inheritance) gem, extracted from it.